# Error building fluxgraph: how do I resolve error during tests while running "mvn package"?

Tags: maven, datomic, tinkerpop

I found some repositories like fluxgraph that had some additional commits meant to update them to use a much more recent tinkerpop blueprints API. I would like to stay as up to  date as possible, but when I checked out each of the following two forks:

https://github.com/jeremiahrhall/fluxgraph
https://github.com/lucascs/fluxgraph

I get very similar error output when running `mvn package`:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/06eb83433ac4b046a5f7

The respective surefire-reports file referenced contains the following:

TEST-com.jnj.fluxgraph.FluxGraphTest.xml     -    https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d8d3e742963d6a51b1d8     -      IllegalArgumentException: It is not possible to set a property on a non-current version of the element
com.jnj.fluxgraph.FluxGraphTest.txt                -    https://gist.github.com/anonymous/542c03e1ce5633f044f7

I don't know how to solve this in order to get fluxgraph working at more recent versions of its dependencies... Can someone help? possibly someone that helped write these repos?

Answer (score 1):

I had an old fork of FluxGraph and created this new branch:

https://github.com/spmallette/fluxgraph/tree/new-versions

which merged in changes from:

https://github.com/lucascs/fluxgraph/tree/new-versions

bringing it to the latest version of Blueprints (2.4.0 currently).  I can get a full `mvn clean install` to run on this branch, though I had to comment out the KeyIndexable tests to do so.  Specifically, this test seemed to cause a problem:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blob/2.4.0/blueprints-test/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/KeyIndexableGraphTestSuite.java#L133

I'm not a datomic guy enough to say what's wrong, but the test basically confirms that you can add some elements to the graph, then index and have stuff work.  So this basically means that with FluxGraph (or at least my branch version of it) you need to define indices up front before loading data to the graph.  Maybe you know enough datomic to fix the issue...if so, it would be nice to get this all organized into a pull request to send back to the original repo owner.